# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-06-03T00:38:48.043Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23

Tags: hibernate, rest, jackson, jax-rs, wildfly

I have java8 LocalDateTime parameters defined in my Entities. 
I have deployed my jax-rs webapp in wildfly 10.

When I make a REST call, I get following exception;

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-06-03T00:38:48.043Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateTimeDeserializer.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateTimeDeserializer.java:36)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:523)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.findDeserializeAndSet(BeanPropertyMap.java:285)
    ... 56 more
```

I have registered  JavaTimeModule in the ObjectMapper;

```
@Provider
public class LocalDateTimeConverterProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>, ParamConverterProvider {

    private final LocalDateTimeConverter converter = new LocalDateTimeConverter();

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public LocalDateTimeConverterProvider() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());


    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
```

Why I get above exception? The default serializer provided by Java8 JavaTimeModule won't work?

Comment: When you serialize, is it in the same format as the date in the exception?

Comment: @peeskillet I have something in this format "2016-06-03T03:44:14.919"

Comment: what version of java time module are you using ? why is the format in the error doesn't match this format "2016-06-03T03:44:14.919" ?

Comment: @ShivV  I use this module; com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule.JavaTimeModule()  Version 2.7.4 (wrong?)

Comment: @ShivV  create time like // LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z"));//

Comment: I mean version of dependency. The default formatter in the LocalTimeDeserailizer uses the ISO date-time formatter that formats or parses a date-time without an offset.

Comment: @ShivV jackson-datatype-jsr310 Version 2.7.4

Comment: so what is the input when you serialize the date is it "2016-06-03T03:44:14.919" or "2016-06-03T00:38:48.043Z" ? The first one should work and second one will work if use ZonedDateTime, that's what I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113703/discussion-between-shiv-v-and-ratha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your local date time deserilizer with ISO_DATE_TIME format to allow the local date time accept time zones.

```
javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
```